# Difference in the 32-bit binaries built using ndk32-r10b and ndk64-r10b

Tags: android, android-ndk, 32bit-64bit

Can anybody explain me what is the difference in 32-bit armeabi binaries compiled using ndk32-r10 build and ndk64-r10 build?

I am having several native libraries in my android project. Initially I was using android ndk-r9d build to compile these binaries for armeabi platform.
Now I have made some changes to one of the library and compiled it using ndk32-r10b build for armeabi.
Everything worked fine.

After this I compiled the same 32-bit binary with ndk64-r10b build for armeabi platform, which got compiled successfully. But at runtime it throws an error that it can not load/find library.
Please note that compilation succedded but it could not load the library at run time.

Can anybody tell me what is the difference in the 32-bit binaries built using ndk32 and ndk64?
Because according to my understanding ndk64 should be able to compile both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries as it is having options for both the platforms.
Is it related to any specific changes made for Android L in the binaries built using ndk64 build, if any?

Thanks for your help in advance.